# how do I find out themed WinForms control's theme-based property values? for DevExpress or for WinForms in general

Tags: winforms, themes, devexpress

I am dealing with this issue in DevExpress.XtraEditors context, but maybe the answer would also apply to other situations where themes are used for WinForms controls.

Basically, how do I find out what collection of property settings does a themed control have? Is there a way for me to go look at the theme definition? Also, can I look at these settings dynamically, i.e. from within the app during execution (much like I can print out unthemed Appearance.BackColor during execution)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what you're looking for, but if you're interested in finding all of a control's (or control `Type`'s) 'Appearance' properties you can use the [TypeDescriptor.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getproperties%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method.   This method returns a [PropertyDescriptorCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptorcollection%28VS.90%29.aspx) from which you can pick out the properties with the `CategoryAttribute.Appearance` property.

You can use this method on an instance of the control:

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(myButtonInstance);
```

Or, on a control `Type`:

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Button));
```

But once you get a `PropertyDescriptorCollection` you can test for the presence of `CategoryAttribute.Appearance` (which means the property appears in the control's 'Appearance' section - assuming Browsable == true)  like this:

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties) {
    if (property.Attributes.Contains(CategoryAttribute.Appearance)) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", property.Name, property.Description);
        // Do whatever...
    }
}
```